# Loading images from internal memory to an imageview

Tags: android

How do I display images from the phone's internal storage in an `ImageView` on android?

No image is loaded using the following code on my phone running on Marshmallow.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/MyFolder/final_photo";
File imgFile = new File(path);
if (imgFile.exists()) {
    imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(imgFile));
}
```

Comment: Use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and see basic [caching mechanisms](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics).

Comment: @ProgrammingMachine5000 it will be helpful if you provide a code snippet

Comment: @Santanu Sur I have tried the following code

Answer (score 0):

Your path doesn't contain a String to an Actual Image!

Images end with `.jpg`, `.png` etc.

As you also said that your Phone is on Marshmallow, you should also Allow the Storage permissions to your App!

Comment: I added the permissions in Manifest

Comment: my internal folder consist of only one image.so I want to display it.Can you help me with a code snippet?

Comment: @Manu You also need to ask the Permissions on Runtime... More info here - https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: In Manifest I have added READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.How to ask permission on Runtime.

Comment: how to load images from internal folder to imageview?